# Firebase does not work when Remote Debugging is enabled?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I don't really have a code sample for this, as its a problem I've noticed time and time again. For whatever reason, whenever I have remote debugging enabled when running my react native app, Firebase does not work. It works consistently and wonderfully without Remote debugging on, but as soon as I enable it, it breaks.

The only reason I need remote debugging is I am trying to see the child properties for a JavaScript object and like how the chrome console nicely displays an object if you print it.

Comment: I used React Native remote debugging with the Firebase Database in the past. But not recently. What's your question?

Comment: I was able to identify the problem, for some reason Facebook Authentication does not work when 
Debug Remotely" is on in react native.. basically I was asking if anyones had this issue or been able to fix it @FrankvanPuffelen